# UITableView cell background color

Tags: iphone

how to set different background colors for cells in a UITableView 
(specifically rainbow color for seven cells)

Answer (score 83):

Set the `backgroundColor` property:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Note that the backgroundColor must be set in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method (from [UITableViewCell reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell)):

> **Note**: If you want to change the
>   background color of a cell (by setting
>   the background color of a cell via the
>   backgroundColor property declared by
>   UIView) you must do it in the
>   tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
>   method of the delegate and not in
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: of
>   the data source. Changes to the
>   background colors of cells in a
>   group-style table view has an effect
>   in iOS 3.0 that is different than
>   previous versions of the operating
>   system. It now affects the area inside
>   the rounded rectangle instead of the
>   area outside of it.

Use the indexPath parameter to achieve the rainbow effect.

Comment: There are obscure cases in which willDisplayCell doesn't get called, having to do with returning from a detail view and not reloading the table.

Comment: You can now simply set cell.contentView.backgroundColor instead, e.g. in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 10):

If you want to set cell color based on some state in the actual cell data object, then this is another approach:

If you add this method to your table view delegate:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor;
}
```

Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method you can do:

```
if (myCellDataObject.hasSomeStateThatMeansItShouldShowAsBlue) {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

This saves having to retrieve your data objects again in the willDisplayCell method.

Comment: It's a nice trick, but I've found cases in which it doesn't work, involving accessory views.

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget to set background color of your tableView to clearColor. Otherwise the clearColor of cell will not be displayed as the background color of tableView will be whiteColor by default. And even when the cell color turns to clearColor whiteColor will be displayed because the tableView background color is still whiteColor. Remenber.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it like so:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:249.0/255 green:237.0/255 blue:224.0/255 alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure UITableViewCell is a subclass of UIView, so:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

For awful rainbow colors, here is an example:

```
static NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor yellowColor], etc..., nil];
cell.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
cell.backgroundVIew.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've subclassed `UITableViewCell`, you can reliably set `self.backgroundColor` in `-layoutSubviews`. At least in my experience, this works in the odd cases where tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: does not.

Answer (score 0):

You may arrive at the conclusion that 'willDisplayCell' is still not working like I did at first. The reason it didn't work for me initially was because I wasn't using colors properly.

Don't forget that when using custom colors you need to divide by 255.0f:

`[UIColor colorWithRed:44/255.0f green:50/255.0f blue:65/255.0f alpha:1];`

Something like the following will result to a white cell:

`//DON'T DO
[UIColor colorWithRed:44 green:50 blue:65 alpha:1];`

making it look like it's not doing anything when it really is setting the background to white.