# Background colour of UICellView Changing

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uicolor

I have a table full of cells, and have changed the background colour by doing the following:

```
    //set the backgorund color for the cells
    UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.3 blue:0.5 alpha:0.5];
    //bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    cell.backgroundView = bg;
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = bg.backgroundColor;
```

---

The problem is that the background colour of the cells changes when you scroll them out of view, and then back into view.

Before:
[image]

After dragging the menu up, then back down:
[image]

---

I've tried to do some troubleshooting on my own and realized that this doesn't happen when I use one of the predefined `UIColor` , for example `[UIColor redColor]`

Comment: what's happens if you remove the AlphaLevel of your color?

Comment: what do you mean by remove the AlphaLevel ?

Comment: Ah okay well when I do that then the cells are white.  Well I think they are clear but the white background of the table shows through.

Comment: Ok, that's a hint. So the dark-purple happens in cause that the cell with alpha is drawn over a cell with color (again and again and again).

"Where" do you set the background color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921300/uitableview-cell-background-color).

Set the BackgroundColor property:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

in:

```
tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

Comment: thanks Thomas, this method still leaves a little bit of the lighter pink on the edge of the cell, but thats fine with me!

Comment: Hey. Hm - but you don't know why :) Let's clear that with you - explain a little bit more.

Comment: After I did what you suggested, it "pre-darkened" all the cells, so now they all appear like the darker ones in the second screen shot.  All I did was implement the `tableview:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath` and set the background colour

Comment: And you removed the other method calls where you set the background color?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should've worded that better, I moved them to the new method

Comment: ok; so the whole cell should be in that color you're chosed. Only, you put another color into the label -> that could be the reason for the lighter pink at the edge.