# Color background cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a very simple table with one large cell inside.  There is static data inside.

I want a repeating tile image as the background of the table.  I think what I need to do is put the image in the cell, not the table, am I on the right track?

I'm trying to simply change the color before moving on to the image but cant even make that work.

I've tried creating a reference outlet for both the table cell as well as the content view and added this code:

```
tblCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
tblContent.backgroundColor =[UIColor redColor];
```

Unfortunately it still shows up as white. Would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: See [UITableView cell background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921300/uitableview-cell-background-color).

Comment: Isn't this what im already doing?

Answer (score 2):

You generally want to edit the appearance of your cell in `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

You can create a color from an image with `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: image]` and have it repeat as your cell's background.

It sounds like you're declaring a static table view. You can't use the `UITableViewDataSource methods`, but you can use the `UITableViewDelegateMethods`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // defaults to white and covers your background
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // turn an image into a color
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"tilePattern"];
    UIColor *pattern = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: img];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = pattern;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is how you change the color of the cell in a tableview.

you need to add the following method after the `CellForRowAtIndexPath` in order to change the color of your cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.row%2 == 0) {
    UIColor *redColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = redColor;
}
}
```

note that any modification of the cell content has to happen in the `WillDisplayCell` method. now you can always change the `UIColor` to whatever you want it to be.

hope this helps you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the color of cell.textLabel so that can see the background color.