# Changing the BackgroundColor in a UITableViewCell has no effect on iOS 7.1

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uistoryboard, uicolor

I am currently working on a small iOS app which is derived from the master - detail template - most of the layout work has been done in Xcode's storyboard.

However, now I am trying to change the background color of a UITableViewCell depending on its content.

My initial idea of doing that was :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

But that had no effect on the rendered cell in the simulator. So I kept searching for different approaches and tried several of them. For example (in various flavors):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIView* bgview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    bgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [cell setBackgroundView:bgview];
}
```

Still, no change in the rendered cell. I am admittedly desperate since this is the final feature missing before I can send the Beta out to my testers...

I would really appreciate any additional hints.

Best regards from Germany

---

EDIT: Oddly enough, I can't even change the cell's color via the setting of the prototype cell in the storyboard ..?

Comment: Have you tried setting the background color to the `contentView` property of the cell?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the background color in cellForRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: See "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921300/uitableview-cell-background-color"

Comment: Does not work either.

Comment: Does table view datasource delegate works correct? (e.g. `cellForRowAtIndexPath`). Did you tried to set breakpoint on `willDisplayCell`?

Comment: I already had the breakpoint idea, which led me to the solution posted below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally got it figured out:

It seems like Xcode messed up with the caching/build process. After I emptied the DerivedData folder everything worked like a charm :

`rm -rf ~/library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`

I have never had this problem before - or even heard of it. Now, I'll make sure to clear this folder first, before wasting hours into investigating a false problem.

I appreciate all the time you guys invested to help me out though !

Answer (score 1):

Set the background to the `contentView` instead:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

From [UITableViewCell Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/contentView):

> The content view of a `UITableViewCell` object is the default superview for content displayed by the cell. If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view so they will be positioned appropriately as the cell transitions into and out of editing mode.